# I wrote a long letter to him

Tags: prepositions

Does it make sense to say "I wrote a long letter for him" instead of "I wrote a long letter to him"? "To" is the most common, I'm not sure if it's grammatically wrong to use "for" in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lawrence is correct; both are correct but have different meanings.  Note that if you meant to write *to* him, a more fluid way to convey the same meaning would be:

> I wrote him a letter.

Here, *him* is used as an [indirect object](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000018.htm) to indicate that *he* (whoever he is) is the recipient.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in both cases (with or without a preposition) many grammars would classify it as an indirect object. Some may argue, though, that versions with a preposition are prepositional objects.

Comment: I think the preposition of an indirect object can be either implicit or explicit, but it must be the agreed form (write 'to', buy 'for', ...).  If not, then the adverbial PP should not be called an indirect object.

Answer (score 3):

Both are grammatical, but they mean different things.

Writing *for* him means that you wrote on his behalf (to someone else).

Writing *to* him means that he was the intended recipient of your letter.

Comment: Writing a letter *for* someone can also mean that you wrote it but did not send it- possibly leaving it in a place the addressed might be expected to find it or possibly entrusting it to someone else to hand over at some point in the future.

Comment: @Jim Wouldn't that be simply *having* a letter for someone?

Comment: No,  I can write a letter, address it to John and give it to you.  You then *have* the letter that I wrote *for* John.  The *for* is about the intended recipient, *having* is about whose possession it’s in currently.

Comment: @Jim I see your point. It seems to me, though, that where *for* is understood in that sense, the item needs to be stated explicitly or the context needs to make it clear. E.g. "I wrote for him" doesn't admit that sense easily, unlike "I wrote *this* for him".

Comment: Agreed.  In this case, the context is OP’s, “*I wrote a long letter for him.*”